# how to record only audio using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, audio-recording

I am working on media recording on IOS. I was able to record with both audio and video using UIImagePickerController. For my specification I want to record only audio. Is it possible with UIImagePickerController? or Do I need to think about other methods?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImagePickerController cannot be used to record audio. Instead you should take a look at the [SpeakHere](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802) sample code from Apple.

Also check [Audio Queue - Recording to a compressed audio format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1615/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008016) on how to record as compressed audio format and conserve disk space.